# Find what button was clicked to launch function

Tags: java, android

i have multiple buttons that use the same onClick function i want to be able to determine what button was clicked to start the function, get the string from that button and save it to a variable to be used later

```js
 public void nextView(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        string buttonClicked=(TextView)findViewById(R.id."whatever_Button_Was_Clicked");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

```html
       <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/botton7"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:onClick="nextView"
            android:layout_column="14"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:width="80dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:minWidth="80dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/botton4_send"
            android:id="@+id/button4_send"
            android:onClick="nextView"
            android:layout_column="15"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:width="80dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:minWidth="80dp" />
```

Comment: Have you considered calling a different method for each button?

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much of code if there are many buttons with same functionality?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "calling a different method for each button?" No, just get the text of the `Button` clicked if that's the only difference in the `onClick()` function

Comment: the method for every button is the same and i don't want to create the same function ten times using the switch solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

```
public void nextView(View v) {
    String clickedButonText = "";
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button7:
            // do something
            clickedButonText=b7.getText().toString(); 
            break;
        case R.id.button4_send:
            // do something else
            clickedButonText=b4Send.getText().toString();
            break;
      }
    }
```

Is this the answer which you are looking for?